# Elegant way to save/load values into an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm basically saving and loading values into an array to feed into a JSON library, and I'm just looking for a more elegant way to do this:

**class properties to array**

```
 return new object[] { path, pathDir, name };
```

**array to class properties**

```
c.path = values[0];
c.pathDir = values[1];
c.name = values[2];
```

Simple solutions that ideally do not require additional run time overheads such as Reflection are appreciated.

Can I do something like this?

```
  c.{path, pathDir, name} = values[0...2]
```

**Edit:** I'm specifically asking for arrays. I know about serialization and JSON and Protobuf and everything else everyone is suggesting.

Comment: You should look at [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Do you mind to do not use Reflection when your data will be sent over the network?

Comment: Use a JSON library that allows you to feed in your classes directly?

Comment: You need to serialise your objects, not an array! There are libraries out there for this.

Comment: could you use an anonymous dynamic object?

Comment: What's the point of saving the properties of an object into an array when you already have the object? If you are dealing with JSON then, well, there are JSON serializers for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this not do the trick?

```
return  new {path= "/Some/Path", pathDir= "SiteRoot", name="MyPath"}
```

Edit:

```
 //Mock function to simulate creating 5 objects with 'CreateArrayOb' function
        public void CreatingObjects()
        {
            var lst = new List<object>();
            for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                lst.Add(CreateArrayOb(new string[] {"Path" + x, "Dir" + x, "Path" + x}));
            }
        }
        public object CreateArrayOb(object[] vals)
        {
            if (vals != null && vals.Any())
            {
                //Switch cases in the event that you would like to alter the object type returned
                //based on the number of parameters sent
                switch (vals.Count())
                {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        return new { path = vals.ElementAt(0), pathDir = vals.ElementAt(1), name = vals.ElementAt(2) };
                }

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Is that functionally equivalent?

Comment: @Geotarget not sure what you are asking here.  Elaborate a little?  Also, edited my post to include additional code.